# jQuery is not defined when using jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js:

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

*ERROR MESSAGE* ***(**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js:319 (anonymous function)**)***

```
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MODULES/SHK/Js/autoCombo/TRYY.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
    window.onload = aa();
    function aa() {
        $("#combx").combobox({

            selected: function(event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's simply because you haven't included the main jQuery library. Instead you're including UI twice (once minified and once non-minified).

Comment: Declare jquery
you have two declarations of jquery-ui custom, one is the original one while the other is minified. try deleting the other one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare the main JQuery library and you have two declarations of jquery-ui-custom, one is the original one and the other is minified version. try deleting the other one. I suggest  you just delete the one that is unminified

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
/** 
 *Your other scripts below 
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are using other jquery related plugins, you should declare the jquery minified (`jquery-1.8.3.min.js`) on the top of other JS.

Since JQuery object has to be defined on `jquery-1.8.3.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the parenthesis!

```
window.onload = aa();//this runs aa instantly, not on window.onload

window.onload = aa;//this gives window.onload event a function to execute when it's time
```