# My script is not running. Am I using the wrong version?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles running my script. When I click the send button a message is supposed to be send to a controller which saves it, but it seems like the button is not working what so ever, nothing happends. Can I be using the wrong version of JQuery or something?

This is my .html with the script:

```
<input id="wallPostInputText" type="text" placeholder="Your message" />
    <input id="wallPostSubmit" type="button" value="Post" />
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wallPostSubmit").click(getMessageText);
    });

    function getMessageText() {
        var messageText = $("#wallPostInputText").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddMessage", "ApiMessage", new { httproute = "" })',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                MessageText: messageText,
                SenderId: @senderID,
                RecieverId: @receiverID
        }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my layout-html from where the jquery is loaded:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

What could be wrong here? I have tried for hours with no success.

Comment: Where is the closing tag on that script? how is the layout rendering the html, and where? what error are you seeing on console?

Comment: Might be duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173404/jquery-is-not-defined-when-using-jquery-ui-1-10-1-custom-js

Comment: what is the url you send to?

Comment: What are `@senderID`, `@receiverID`, and the string containing '@Url' supposed to be?  Those throw "SyntaxError: Invalid character: '@'" in the console.

Comment: @ZivWeissman it's there in my code, somehow I did not include it here. I'm not getting any errors. It's like I haven't even clicked the button.

Comment: @DevangNaghera I checked it out and tried to change my scripts into the same version without success.

Comment: @user3561607 To a function in the ApiMessageController

[HttpPost]
        public void AddMessage([FromBody]Message newMessage)
        {
            database.Message.Add(newMessage);
            database.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: @DanielBeck Those are local variables from where I get the values from sessions and ViewBag.

Comment: OK --but that's not valid javascript, so if you're trying to run this as is it's going to throw errors.  If those are some other language that gets parsed into js you should either post the final parsed javascript, or tag this question with whatever language that is so people familiar with it will be able to weigh in.

Comment: @DanielBeck

@{
    int receiverID = ViewBag.UserProfile;
    int senderID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PersonID"]);
}

How are you seeing errors? I'm not getting anything when I click the button.

Comment: Again, none of that is javascript -- it looks like ASP.NET I think? (Which I don't speak, so I don't know if this is related to the problem you're having here or not.)   You can see in-browser error messages by opening the console in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling the document ready function twice,

Once with jQuery(function($)) and another one on document ready.

Try changing that to:

```
<script>
  function getMessageText() {
    //Your code
  }
  jQuery(function ($) {
        //The document ready part goes here
        $("#wallPostSubmit").click(getMessageText);
      });
</script>
```

If this is not working out for you, post your full code so we can try to help.

Also make sure on "Network" tab on your browser if you are indeed loading the jquery.js

Comment: jQuery supports multiple ready calls including nested calls. If the document ready event has already fired, any subsequent calls (such as the nested one in OP's question) are made immediately. So that isn't the problem, although I do agree it's better style to not have the nested ready call since it is not needed.

Comment: @MichaelGeary yeah point taken, still strange to me, what happens with the function definition? which is on the outer document ready, that should work? didn't use jQuery in a while :P

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser deverloper console, open the network tab, reload your page. Do you have any 404 or 500 response for one of your javascript file ?

jquery min is probably not loaded - removed the '~/' in your path

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

starting your file path with ~/ will probably resolve in a 500 or 404 - you'd better stick to Scripts/jquery , or better :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

by putting your Scripts folder at the root of your site folder .